# Can't find uploaded files in temp directory after script execution ends

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I am trying out a tutorial on W3 schools to learn how to create forms for PHP uploads.

To this end, I have the following two files as shown on [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp):

The HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding PHP file as follows:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

When I save the above files onto my localhost, and execute the up.html file, the PHP produces an output as follows:

> Upload: AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
>   Type: application/x-x509-ca-cert
>   Size: 1.4853515625 Kb
>   Stored in: /tmp/phpK0YqyL

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find this `/tmp/phpK0YqyL`.

Can anyone suggest where this file could possibly be located?

In reality, I would also like to know how one could specify the path to directly upload the file to (presumably this would be somewhere in `$_FILES` array).

Comment: You can set the upload folder in `php.ini`

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows in which case try `C:\Windows\Temp`.

Comment: Hi Marcel: I use Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The /tmp/ folder is a folder to temporarily store the file for processing or reading.
If you want to access the file later on, you need to save the file to the server with the [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function

Comment: Hi XpertEase, I have tried your suggestion and added the following line to my PHP code:"move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);" However, I dont see the file in /upload directory. Strange. Any other suggestions? I have tried searching for the file too, but couldnt find it: Really annoying!

Comment: does the folder upload already exist? And maybe try changing "/upload/" to "upload/"

Comment: @Xpert: Well, Ive tried both approaches: (a) run the code without creating the folder upload (assuming PHP will create this folder for me) and (b) creating the folder called "upload" on my local file system and then uploading the file. On both approaches, I dont see the uploaded file (I am using /upload instead of /upload/). I also wanted to say that I save the up.html and upload_file.php on my local file system /var/www before excecuting the up.html script on my browser. Still cant figure out where this file is stored :( FYI: I am new to PHP.

Comment: @John: FYI: i noticed ;) we all started somewhere. But you say you are using /upload, try upload/ as stated above. You might also try adding the full path of your destination. And check the rights of the folder.

Comment: @Xpert: damn.. you were right.. It was the file permissions.. chmod 777 solved the problem. Thanks a lot for this quick response. I use Django, so PHP is kind of weird. Anyways, accepted your answer :)

Comment: @John: Thank you. Glad I could be of any help!

Answer (score 5):

Temporary uploaded files are removed when the script execution ends.

Answer (score 1):

remember to set /temp/folder for read write files